Как понять, что за устройства в выводе команды sensors?
Every 2,0s: sensors                                                                                                                                                                 Honor: Thu Aug 29 23:40:56 2024

ath11k_hwmon-pci-0200
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +38.0°C

nvme-pci-0300
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +36.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +80.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +36.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +38.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +80.0°C  (crit = +110.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +80.4°C

amdgpu-pci-0400
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:      987.00 mV
vddnb:       949.00 mV
edge:         +65.0°C
PPT:          29.00 W

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          14.70 V
curr1:         2.69 A


Ноутбук стал выключаться при нагрузке, sensors выдает следующее. Как понять, кто такие acpitz-acpi-0 и k10temp-pci-00c3?

k10temp-pci-00c3 это устройство процессоров амд. находится в самом процессоре. может показываться неправильно, если в драйвере нет поддержки вашего процессора.
acpitz-acpi-0 смотри в /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/device/path - 0 это процессор в большинстве случаев.
